# Multiply two columns while creating table SQL

Tags: php, sql

Okay, here is the deal. I have one table already created:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS worker(     workerID INT(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                                        name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                                        surname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                                        sex VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                                        email VARCHAR(50),
                                        phone VARCHAR(20),
                                        date DATE NOT NULL,
                                        salary int(5) NOT NULL,
                                        )";
```

Now I have to create one more table named "workplace" with attributes (IDworkplace, IDworker, coefficient, hourlyRate, brutto)

brutto is calculated like coefficient*salary, but salary is from the first table.

Is there any way I can implement that brutto=coefficient*salary while creating the table "workplace"?

Comment: Storing calculated values is a violation of database normalization

Comment: Your target is strange! You need to just create the `workplace` table with the column `brutto` and when you insert data to this table, fetch the worker's salary using foreign_key and then multiply with coefficient to save into brutto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view that joins `worker` and `workplace` (that has to be created without `brutto`).

```
CREATE VIEW workplace_with_brutto
SELECT wp.idworkplace,
       wp.idworker,
       wp.coefficient,
       wp.hourlyrate,
       wp.coefficient * w.salary brutto
       FROM workplace wp
            LEFT JOIN worker w.workerid = wp.idworker;
                      ON w.
```

You should not materialize `brutto` as it's dependent of other values. I.e. it is redundant and redundant data can cause inconsistencies.

Comment: How can I display data from that "view table" through php? I'm sorry but I'm begginer in this and this is my assignment in school.

Comment: @probablynotmyname: A view can be queried the same way as a table can be queried.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

No , You can't define a generated column based on values from other tables. Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> The generation expression can refer to other columns in the table, but not other generated columns. Any functions and operators used must be immutable. References to other tables are not allowed.

one way is to make a trigger on the workplace table (and probably on the worker table to capture salary changes) which is not recommended

or the best way would be to make a view based on those two table without adding any column on the table fro that :

```
create view vworkplace as
select workplace.* ,  coefficient*salary brutto
from worker
join workplace
on workplace.IDworker = worker.workerID
```